# Selecting MYSQL column conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Example schema for my question is given at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbe5b) and as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `player1id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player2id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`player1id`,`player2id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `players` values
(1,5),
(1,7),
(5,3),
(5,4),
(2,1);
```

In a online game, I want to select opponent, which could be in player `player1id` or `player2id`.

Example Input/ output needed

```
Input 1: Output 5, 7, 2
Input 5: Output 1, 3 ,4
& so on.
```

That is, required data could be in any column but I need output in single column conditionally or any other way. I heard about MySQL conditional column but could not create query to get required output. Can someone please help with required query.

**Edit**

Based on [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,6639,6677#msg-6677), I run following query but failed.

```
SELECT IF(PLAYER1ID IS 1,PLAYER2ID as opponent,PLAYER1ID as opponent) 
FROM players
WHERE PLAYER1ID = 1 OR PLAYER2ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you may use `case when then` syntax as below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN player1id = 1 THEN player2id ELSE player1id  END
FROM players WHERE player1id =1 OR player2id=1;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN player1id = 1 THEN player2id WHEN player2id =1 THEN player1id  END
FROM players WHERE player1id =1 OR player2id=1;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogendra. I try `SELECT CASE WHEN player1id =1
THEN player2id
WHEN player2id =1
THEN player1id
END AS opponent
FROM players
WHERE player1id =1
OR player2id =1` to add custom name of column based on your reply. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
select player1id from players where player2id=1
union
select player2id from players where player1id=1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbe5b/7)

Comment: Thanks Anand, Its working. But I prefer conditional column and in link of edit part in question. IS it also possible? +1 for help and working solution.

Comment: Just as justification, I give only minimal example in my schema but I've to select data from multiple tables and need to select at least 15-20 columns. Thus repeating query twice before and after `union` is not efficient way. However thanks to propose one more way and I'm sure it will be helpful for me in future, in some other scenario.

Comment: Yeah you are right.I thought only 2 columns so gave this solution.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to give you what you're looking for:

```
SET @PlayerId = 1;
SELECT `player2id` AS 'Other Player ID'
  FROM `players`
 WHERE `player1id` = @PlayerId
   AND `player2id` != @PlayerId

 UNION
 SELECT `player1id`
  FROM `players`
 WHERE `player2id` = @PlayerId
   AND `player1id` != @PlayerId;


SET @PlayerId = 5;
SELECT `player2id` AS 'Other Player ID'
  FROM `players`
 WHERE `player1id` = @PlayerId
   AND `player2id` != @PlayerId

 UNION
SELECT `player1id`
  FROM `players`
 WHERE `player2id` = @PlayerId
   AND `player1id` != @PlayerId;
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I took `@PlayerId` part from your reply and add it to @Yogendra Singh reply. This will be helpful as we need to put variable in 4 places of accepted answer.