# MYSQL Return a value if exists, if not return another

Tags: mysql, select

I have a simple table (`items`) which has two fields in particular: `group_name` and `single_name`

Only a handful have a value for `group_name` but I need to return one or the other as `display_name`.

If `group_name` exists then that is returned (i.e `group_name as display_name`), if `group_name` is NULL then return `single_name as display name`.

I'm sure I could do lots of nested select statements, but I'm sure MYSQL has a much easier way of doing this using an if statement. i.e in PHP code I would do something like this:

```
if (group_name IS null) {
    display_name = single_name
} else {
    display_name = group_name
}
```

I will be rendering the data in Angular so would prefer the SQL / API server did do the work rather than the client at render time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL equivalent of DECODE function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706100/mysql-equivalent-of-decode-function-in-oracle)

Comment: I did end up using CASE, the link you sent is sort of appropriate but the title is too complex and 'indirect' for me to have found it to help me as it refers to an ORACLE statement that I have no knowledge of) but a nice Boolean MYSQL only example has its place no?

Comment: No, if you did a good search on it, you would have found these also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226520/selecting-mysql-column-
conditionally --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to solve this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(group_name, single_name) AS display_name FROM items
```

... for the completeness you can also use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN group_name IS NULL THEN single_name ELSE group_name END AS display_name FROM items
```

... or you can use [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT IF(group_name IS NULL, single_name, group_name) AS display_name FROM items
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/853182/3

Comment: Each one brilliant, I settled on the CASE statement. Many thanks for the swift response

Answer (score 3):

You can also use IF

```
SELECT 
 IF(group_name IS NULL, single_name, group_name) AS display_name 
FROM 
 [table]
```

Or CASE

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN group_name IS NULL 
  THEN single_name 
  ELSE group_name
 END 
  AS display_name
FROM 
 [table]
```