# How do I hide column value if another field has a certain condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a basic website that has a form. This form captures the following information from a user and stores it in the PHPMyAdmin table:

**First Name, Surname, Title, Description, Email Address, Display Email Address (Yes/No).**

An example of input would be:

**David, Beckham, Mr, Hello I am a boy, david@hotmail.com, Yes**

Also on the website, I have a table that shows a list of all the users stored in my database through the use of this PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, UserDescription, 
UserEmailAddress FROM Users";
```

How would I edit this SQL so that if a user answers "No" to the "Display Email" field, their row would omit their email address from the row. For example:

**David, Beckham, Mr, Hello I am a boy, david@hotmail.com, Yes**

**Lucy, Sky, Mrs, Hello I am a girl,            , No**

I have tried the following query, but have had no luck so far:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EmailReveal = 'yes'
        THEN SELECT *
        ELSE SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, UserDescription
   END AS col 
FROM Users;
```

Comment: what you mean with "no luck"? what you get?

Comment: Hello Giacomo, I get the following error#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *
            ELSE SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, ' at line 2

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226520/selecting-mysql-column-conditionally

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    UserID, 
    UserForeName, 
    UserSurname, 
    UserTitle, 
    UserDescription, 
    CASE WHEN showemailcondition THEN UserEmailAddress ELSE '' END `Email`
FROM Users
```

This is how you would use a CASE WHEN in a simple way for this.

Comment: . . Perhaps the question was edited after you answered, but it clearly specifies that the values of `EmailReveal` are `'yes'` and `'no'`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `union`  but for that you have to be same number of column so you could use '' blank string for making same number of column in both selection

```
 SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, UserDescription 
,col1,col2 ---coln FROM Users
 where EmailReveal = 'yes'
 union
  SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, UserDescription ,
 '',''--''
 FROM Users
 where EmailReveal <> 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID, UserForeName, UserSurname, UserTitle, IF(UserEmailAddress = 'Yes',UserDescription,'') AS UserDescription,UserEmailAddress FROM Users";
```