# MySQL - IF-THEN statement with user-defined variable

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I would like to compare a user-defined variable via an IF-THEN statement:

```mysql
SET @num = 10;

IF @num > 7 then
    select * from person;
ELSE
    select name from person;
END IF;
```

How could I do that?
Currently I get an error near the IF @num > 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting MYSQL column conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226520/selecting-mysql-column-conditionally)

Comment: Kind of, but I think, when using multiple columns that solution might be hard to read, also '*' might not be working.
I would rather prefer the solition by Bill Karwin.
But thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compound statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html) like IF/THEN/ELSE are only supported in MySQL's stored routine language.

This is from the manual:

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events.

Typically if you need to run SQL queries conditionally and you aren't using stored routines, you would put the conditional logic into some client application programming language, e.g. Java, Python, Go, PHP, or whatever is your favorite language.

From its earliest days, SQL was intended to be used in combination with other programming languages.

If you really can't write the code in a client application, here's a workaround that can work for instance to run your example in an SQL script:

```
SET @num = 10;

SET @sql = IF(@num > 7,
              'select * from person',
              'select name from person');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If you have more complex conditional code, this workaround might not be practical.

Comment: Thank you for your additional example. It helped me very much.

Comment: I still recommend that if you need to implement conditional logic, then you should write some code in a client application. That's what I'd do. It is so easy to whip up a Python script or something that I write one just to test something while I answer a Stack Overflow question, and then I delete the script.

Comment: Thanks.
For database-independence I currently (want to) store all direct SQL-queries in a dictionary, which is (normally) created only once at runtime, and when I create the query at client side (in e.g. C# code) the dictionary would need to be reset and then created again.
I feared that the recreation might impact performance, hence my approach to get the if working in SQL, but it seems to build a new dictionary is very fast.
So I will now use your example for queries which are build less complex and for complex ones I will just recreate the dictionary with the updated SQL-query.

Comment: When you say database-independence, do you mean that you want this code to run on multiple brands of database, e.g. MySQL, Microsoft, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite...? If so, then you should check the documentation of each brand you need to support, because `IF()` expressions like I showed aren't necessarily supported. Not every brand supports the same syntax of SQL expressions.

Comment: Oh, no I won't use just one query for different databases.
I just have a class which contains multiple dictionaries, where each one stands for a specific query, but it contains different implementations (mssql, mysql, ...).

Then ,at runtime a dictionary is created for a specific database-system, which just goes over those other dictionaries in that class and collects the queries by a specific key, mysql for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add logical operators like IF-THEN statements in your queries, use stored procedures:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedue sp_persons( in_num int )
begin

IF in_num > 7 then
    select * from person;
ELSE
    select name from person;
END IF;

end
$$

call sp_persons( 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no way around a stored procedure?

Comment: That is what procdures are for. To add logic to your queries and offload the logic to db.